# Lucene : Best way to store and query a datastructure

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I have a product whose price vary with day of week and season (like hotel room).
So consider , i have a rate card (and I can attach multiple rate cards to a product)

RateCard fields are

```
DateTime startdate
DateTime enddate
int priority
double price
double mon_surcharge
double tue_surcharge
double wed_surcharge
double thur_surcharge
double fri_surcharge
double sat_surcharge
double sun_surcharge
```

So my question is - how can i find product with order : start and end date , with range of min-max prices  and sort them by price
Any suggestions

Comment: An interesting use case may I know if the product data is only used to find the queried product or used for analytics? So you're trying to search for in this case I could refer you to consider `RedisSearch` for indexing and searching with `Aggregate` values meanwhile you can `Set` the expiration time values because your data changes periodically.

Answer (score 0):

In LuceneNET I'd recommend that you change the structure of the price data to mon_price, tue_price, etc rather then having daily surcharges that must be added to price.

If you go with a daily price field then doing a range search on that field (or fields) should work great.